# Compilation error after reconfigure maven .pom file to collect browserstack reports inside jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, browserstack

I am trying to configure maven project with TestNG to get Browserstack Automate reports inside Jenkins builds following official manual https://www.browserstack.com/automate/jenkins

The full log is here https://codeshare.io/2KgwqX

But I am getting error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile (default) on project xxx: Execution default of goal com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile failed: multiple points -> [Help 1]
```

My pom file looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <jdk.source.version>1.8.0_131</jdk.source.version>
    <jdk.target.version>1.8.0_131</jdk.target.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>automate-testassist</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dev9</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdriver-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0.pr4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suitexml.file}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <profileId>${profileId}</profileId>
                    <config>${config}</config>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>automate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.source.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.target.version}</target>
                <complianceLevel>${jdk.source.version}</complianceLevel>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
<!-- profiles -->
<profiles>
    <!--profile>
        <id>allow-snapshots</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>snapshots-repo</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile-->
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <profileId>local</profileId>
            <suitexml.file>src/test/resources/testng.local.xml</suitexml.file>
            <dataCollector>s16</dataCollector>
            <scriptFile>xxx</scriptFile>
            <pjID>xxx</pjID>
            <environment></environment>
            <config>local.conf.json</config>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <profileId>dev</profileId>
            <dataCollector>s16</dataCollector>
            <scriptFile>xxx</scriptFile>
            <pjID>xxx</pjID>
            <suitexml.file>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suitexml.file>
            <environment></environment>
            <config>parallel.conf.json</config>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>staging</id>
        <properties>
            <profileId>staging</profileId>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <dataCollector>s16</dataCollector>
            <scriptFile>xxx</scriptFile>
            <pjID>xxx</pjID>
            <suitexml.file>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suitexml.file>
            <environment></environment>
            <config>parallel.conf.json</config>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>live</id>
        <properties>
            <profileId>live</profileId>
            <dataCollector>s16</dataCollector>
            <scriptFile>xxx</scriptFile>
            <pjID>xxx</pjID>
            <suitexml.file>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suitexml.file>
            <environment></environment>
            <config>parallel.conf.json</config>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The full output

```
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/xxx/repos/selenium-tests/xxx-tests -Dmaven.home=/home/xxx/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/xxx/ch-0/172.3317.53/plugins/maven/lib/maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=/home/xxx/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/172.3317.53/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf -javaagent:/home/xxx/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/172.3317.53/lib/idea_rt.jar=34649:/home/xxx/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/172.3317.53/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/xxx/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/172.3317.53/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.2 clean test -Plocal
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxx 4.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ xxx ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/xxx/repos/selenium-tests/xxx-tests/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ xxx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ xx ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /home/xxx/repos/selenium-tests/xxx-tests/target/classes
[INFO] /home/xxx/repos/selenium-tests/xxx-tests/src/main/java/webdriver/WebDriverFactory.java: /home/xxx/repos/selenium-tests/xxx-tests/src/main/java/webdriver/WebDriverFactory.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /home/xxx/repos/selenium-tests/xxx-tests/src/main/java/webdriver/WebDriverFactory.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ xxx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ xxx ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files to /home/xxx/repos/selenium-tests/xxx-tests/target/test-classes
[INFO] /home/xxx/repos/selenium-tests/xxx-tests/src/test/java/com/xxx/TestNgTestBase.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /home/xxx/repos/selenium-tests/xxx-tests/src/test/java/com/xxx/TestNgTestBase.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile (default) @ xxx ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.969 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-14T16:47:29+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/471M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile (default) on project xxx: Execution default of goal com.browserstack:automate-maven-plugin:0.7.2-SNAPSHOT:test-compile failed: multiple points -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just in java version as a string, I have changed to

```
<properties>
    <jdk.source.version>1.8</jdk.source.version>
    <jdk.target.version>1.8</jdk.target.version>
</properties>
```